# Animate each DIVs for each child element with WOW.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Is there a way to animate each DIVs with a delay and only animate when it's on the viewport using WOW.js or any JS plugin that would do the trick?. What WOW.js does right now is it animates everything on it's line of view.

I would want it to work as how this JSFiddle example shows http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/VS8tQ/3/

var delay = 0;

```
$('.block-item:lt(16)').each(function(){
    $(this).delay(delay).animate({
        opacity:0
    },500);
    delay += 500;
});
```

But with a WOW.js effect where it will only animate when I scroll down and see the divs.

---

PS: It would really be awesome if someone could show me a code or make me one that works very well with [Velocity.js](http://julian.com/research/velocity/) & [Waypoint.js](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/) (optional)